# Redirecting audio / creating alternate sound paths in Android

Tags: android, audio, alsa, opensl

Does anyone have experience (using OpenSL ES, ALSA, etc.) with redirecting audio or creating new sound paths in Android? The end goal is to create a virtual microphone to replace the external microphone, where one can play audio files as if they were speaking into the microphone. Applications accessing the microphone with `AudioSource.MIC` should use this alternate stream. It's not necessary for it to work with voice calls, I believe achieving that sort of functionality is harder as it's all done within the radio.

Any ideas on where to begin? I've done some research with OpenSL and ALSA, but it looks like I'll need to package new firmware (ROM) in order to define custom audio paths. If it can be avoided I'd like to create an application-level solution. The phones are 'rooted' (have su binaries). The target device for this is the Samsung Galaxy S4 Google Edition (GT-i9505G). Specifically I'm looking for audio driver configurations / source code or any references for the i9505G.

Thanks in advance!

edit - I've checked out the CyanogenMod 10.2 source tree, along with the jfltexx drivers and kernel. Here are the contents of kernel/samsung/jf/sound: http://pastebin.com/7vK8THcZ. Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: This is likely to be platform-specific (e.g. Qualcomm, NVidia, Samsung Exynos, ...), as the available ALSA controls differ between different platforms. An application-level solution is probably out of the question, even if you've got root access. I implemented a new AudioSource on a Qualcomm platform once, to allow apps to record the currently playing audio, and IIRC I had to make changes in the platform ALSA drivers, in the Audio HAL and in the UCM (ALSA Use Case Manager) configuration files, as well as in frameworks/base or frameworks/av.

Comment: @Michael I'd also like to be able to record the currently playing audio, can you elaborate or point to some references as a starting point? I'm pleasantly surprised that someone else has attempted this, there's very little information about it out there about the microphone portion (or maybe I'm not looking hard enough!). I hoped that if I could get the microphone portion working it would be relatively trivial to create a source for recording the system audio output. Do you know if the drivers are a part of AOSP or if I'd have to find them elsewhere (i.e. a Cyanogen branch)? Thank you.

Comment: I no longer have access to the code. But I outlined what I did in very broad terms in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255832/android-audio-loopback/15268887#15268887). [This](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/kernel/msm/tree/sound/soc/msm/msm-pcm-routing.c?h=jb_2.5.4) and [this](https://code.google.com/p/android-source-browsing/source/browse/snd_soc_msm_2x_Fusion3?repo=device--lge--mako) are some of the files involved (on the platform I was working with).

Comment: I _think_ that I simplified the solution a bit later by feeding `SLIM_0_RX` into the `AFE_PCM_RX Port Mixer` instead. (`SLIM_0_RX` is the DAI typically used for most playback, and `AFE_PCM_RX` is a "dummy" DAI used specifically for creating loopbacks, which is used e.g. for USB and WiFi audio output).

Comment: @Michael Thank you for your help. I'll do some research and see what I can do. In the meantime I've added a bounty to see if I can get this question more views; maybe someone else has some source code / configs laying around. Thanks again.

Comment: The GT-i9505G appears to be using a Qualcomm APQ8064T chipset, so you can find all the code for the platform at the CodeAurora Forum (e.g. [here are some of the sound drivers for kitkat](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/kernel/msm/tree/sound/soc/msm?h=kk_3.5_rb1.16). Of course, Samsung will make some modifications to the code, and I don't know which parts they modify or by how much.

Comment: @Michael I've edited the question, I pulled a Cyanogen source tree and the kernel for jf. In `kernel/samsung/jf/sound/soc/msm` there's a file called `msm-pcm-routing.c`. Does this sound like a promising start? My idea was to make a new audio source and sink accessible by `SoundPool` and `AudioRecord` for use in the application layer.

Comment: Yes, you might have to make changes in that file. You'll most likely also have to make changes in the ALSA UCM file (snd_soc_msm_2x_fusion3, or whichever one your phone uses); maybe in some of the code under hardware/qcom/audio; and probably in frameworks/av and frameworks/base to add the Java-level stuff that apps see and the necessary glue between the Java layer and the audio HAL.

Comment: @Michael Thanks again for your help, it looks like I'm not going to get an answer for that bounty though. If you'd like to combine your comments and put them in an answer, I'll give it to you.

Comment: @Michael and jpalm, Thanks for wonderful discussion....I am also looking into similar thing. I am looking around for two instance of mic where one will be actually capturing data from device and other is just copying data from it...I believe this copying of buffer can be implemented in T i n y A L S A or Audio Fling er, this way two apps can open mic, can you guys provide further direction on this? Thanks.

Comment: @JRC: We had this functionality on some of the phones I've worked on. It was a stream splitter class that allowed multiple recording clients to access the same data coming from one physical input device, and was implemented as part of libaudioflinger by the platform vendor (which was ST-Ericsson in this case). I don't remember much of how it was implemented, as I wasn't involved in writing it; I only looked at it when we got bug reports that involved recording.

Comment: @Michael, thanks, are there any example or reference available anywhere for Stream Splitter in audio flinger?

Comment: @JRC: None that I know of. It's not a standard feature of Android. It was a proprietary customization provided by the platform vendor to the OEM.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I once implemented the functionality you're after on a phone based on Qualcomm's APQ8064 platform (which seems to be nearly the same platform as the one in your target device). Below is a summary of what I can recall from this, as I no longer have access to the code I wrote, or an environment where I can easily do these kinds of modifications. So if this answer reads like a mess of fragmentary memories, that's because that's exactly what it is.

This info may also apply more-or-less to other Qualcomm platforms (like the MSM8960 or MSM8974), but will most likely be completely useless for platforms from other vendors (NVidia Tegra, Samsung Exynos, TI OMAP, etc).

A brief note: The method I used means that the audio that the recording application gets will have gone through mixing / volume control in the Android multimedia framework and/or the platform's multimedia DSP. So if you're playing something at 75% volume, recording it, and then playing back the recording at 75% volume it might end up sounding pretty quiet. If you want to get unprocessed PCM data (after decoding, but before mixing / volume control) you'll have to look into some other approach, e.g. customizing the `AudioFlinger`, but that's not something I've tried or can provide info on.

---

A few locations of interest:

[The platform's audio drivers](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/kernel/msm/tree/sound/soc/msm?h=kk_3.5_rb1.16). Particularly the [msm-pcm-routing.c file](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/kernel/msm/tree/sound/soc/msm/msm-pcm-routing.c?h=kk_3.5_rb1.16).

[The ALSA UCM (Use-Case Manager) settings file](https://android.googlesource.com/device/lge/mako/+/jb-mr1-dev/snd_soc_msm_2x_Fusion3). This is just an example UCM settings file. There are many variants of these files depending on the exact platform used, so your's may have a slightly different name (though it *should* start with `snd_soc_msm_`), and its contents will probably also differ slightly from the one I linked to.
**NOTE for Kitkat and later:** The UCM settings files were used on Jellybean (and possibly ICS). My understanding is that these settings have been moved to a file named [`mixer_paths.xml`](https://android.googlesource.com/device/lge/mako/+/master/mixer_paths.xml) on Kitkat. The contents are pretty much the same, just in a different format.

[The audio HAL code](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/hardware/qcom/audio/tree/?h=jb_3.2_rb5.43). The ALSA UCM is present in `libalsa-intf`, and the `AudioHardware` / `AudioPolicyManager` / `ALSADevice` code is present in `audio-alsa`. Note that this code is for Jellybean, since that's the lastest version that I'm familiar with. The directory structure (and possibly some of the files / classes) differs on Kitkat.

If you open up the UCM settings file and search for `"HiFiPROXY Rx"` you'll find something like this:

```
SectionVerb
Name "HiFiPROXY Rx"

EnableSequence
    'AFE_PCM_RX Audio Mixer MultiMedia1':1:1
EndSequence

DisableSequence
    'AFE_PCM_RX Audio Mixer MultiMedia1':1:0
EndSequence

# ALSA PCMs
CapturePCM 0
PlaybackPCM 0
EndSection
```

This defines a *verb* (essentially the basis of an audio use-case; there are also *modifiers* that can be applied on top of verbs for stuff like simultaneous playback and recording) with the name `"HiFiPROXY Rx"` (the `HiFi` moniker is used for most non-voice-call verbs, `PROXY` refers to the audio device used, and `Rx` means output) and specifies which ALSA control(s) to write to, and what to write to them, when the use-case should be enabled / disabled. Finally it lists the ALSA PCM playback / capture devices to use in this use-case. For example, `PlaybackPCM 0` means that playback device 0 should be used (the ALSA card is implied to be the one that represents the built-in hardware codec, which typically is card 0). These verbs are selected by the audio HAL based on the use-case (music playback, voice call, recording, ...), what accessories you've got attached, etc.

---

If you look up `"AFE_PCM_RX Audio Mixer"` in the [msm_qdsp6_widgets table](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/kernel/msm/tree/sound/soc/msm/msm-pcm-routing.c?h=kk_3.5_rb1.16#n2719) in `msm-pcm-routing.c` you'll see that it refers to a [list of mixer controls named `afe_pcm_rx_mixer_controls`](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/kernel/msm/tree/sound/soc/msm/msm-pcm-routing.c?h=kk_3.5_rb1.16#n1691) that looks like this:

```
static const struct snd_kcontrol_new afe_pcm_rx_mixer_controls[] = {
    SOC_SINGLE_EXT("MultiMedia1", MSM_BACKEND_DAI_AFE_PCM_RX,
    MSM_FRONTEND_DAI_MULTIMEDIA1, 1, 0, msm_routing_get_audio_mixer,
    msm_routing_put_audio_mixer),
    SOC_SINGLE_EXT("MultiMedia2", MSM_BACKEND_DAI_AFE_PCM_RX,
    ... and so on...
```

This lists the front end DAIs that you are allowed to connect to the back end DAI (`AFE_PCM_RX`). To get an idea of how these relate to one another, see [these diagrams](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sound/alsa/soc/DPCM.txt).
`AFE_PCM_RX` and `AFE_PCM_TX` is a pair of DAIs on some of Qualcomm's platforms that implement a sort of dummy/proxy device. What you do is feed audio into `AFE_PCM_RX` which then gets processed by the multimedia DSP (QDSP), and then you can read it back through `AFE_PCM_TX`. This is used to implement USB and WiFi audio routing, and also A2DP IIRC.

Back to the `AFE_PCM_RX Audio Mixer MultiMedia1` line: This says that you're feeding `MultiMedia1` into the `AFE_PCM_RX Audio Mixer`. `MultiMedia1` is used for normal playback/recording, and corresponds to `pcmC0D0` (you should be able to list the devices on your phone with `adb shell cat /proc/asound/devices`). There are other front end DAIs, like `MultiMedia3` and `MultiMedia5` that are used in special cases like low-latency playback and low-power audio playback.
When you feed `MultiMedia1` to the `AFE_PCM_RX Audio Mixer` everything you write to playback device 0 on card 0 will be fed into the `AFE_PCM_RX` back end DAI. To read it back you could set up a UCM verb that does something like `'MultiMedia1 Mixer AFE_PCM_TX':1:1`, and then you'd read from `pcmC0D0c` (which should be the default ALSA capture device).

---

A simple test would be to pull the UCM settings file from your phone (should be located somewhere under `/system/etc/`) and amend the `"HiFi"` verb's `EnableSequence` with something like:

```
'AFE_PCM_RX Audio Mixer MultiMedia1':1:1
'AFE_PCM_RX Audio Mixer MultiMedia3':1:1
'AFE_PCM_RX Audio Mixer MultiMedia5':1:1
```

(and similarly in the `DisableSequence`, but with `:1:0` at the end of each line).

Then go to the `"Capture Music"` modifier (this is the poorly named modifier for normal recording) and change `SLIM_0_TX` to `AFE_PCM_TX`.

Copy your modified UCM settings file back to the phone (requires root permission), and reboot the phone. Then start some playback (have a wired headset/headphone attached, and disable touch sounds so that the low-latency verb doesn't get selected), and start a recording from `AudioSource.MIC`. Afterwards, check the recording and see if you were able to record the playback audio. If not, then perhaps the low-power audio verb was selected and you'll have to modify the `"HiFi Low Power"` verb similarly to what you did with the `"HiFi"` verb. It will help you if you have all the debug prints enabled in the audio HAL (i.e. uncomment `#define LOG_NDEBUG 0` in all the cpp files where you can find it) so that you can see which UCM verbs / modifiers that get selected.

---

The modification I described above gets a bit tedious since you have to cover all the `MultiMedia` front end DAIs for all relevant verbs and modifiers.
IIRC, I was able to simplify this into just a single line per verb/modifier:

```
'AFE_PCM_RX Port Mixer SLIM_0_RX':1:1
```

If you look at the `"HiFi`", `"HiFi Low Power`", `"HiFi Lowlatency"` verbs you'll see that they all use the `SLIMBUS_0_RX` back end DAI, so I'm taking advantage of that by using the `AFE_PCM_RX Port Mixer` which lets me set up a connection from a back end DAI to another back end DAI. If you look at the `afe_pcm_rx_port_mixer_controls` and `intercon` tables in `msm-pcm-routing.c` you'll notice that there's no `SLIM_0_RX` entry for `AFE_PCM_RX Port Mixer`, so you'd have to add those yourself (it's just a matter of copy-pasting some of the existing lines and changing the names).

---

Some of the other changes you'd probably have to make:

- In [frameworks/base](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/frameworks/base/tree/?h=aosp-new/master) and [frameworks/av](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/frameworks/av/tree/?h=aosp-new/master) (e.g. `AudioManager`, `AudioService`, `AudioSystem`) you'd have to add a new `AudioSource` constant and make sure that it gets recognized in all the necessary places.
- In the UCM settings file you'd have to add some new verbs / modifiers to set up the ALSA controls properly when your new `AudioSource` is used.
- In the audio HAL you'd have to make some changes so that your new verbs / modifiers get selected when your new `AudioSource` is used. Note that there's a base class of `AudioPolicyManagerALSA` called `AudioPolicyManagerBase` which you also might have to modify (it's [located elsewhere in the source tree](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/hardware/libhardware_legacy/tree/audio?h=kk_2.7_rb1.21)).

Comment: Really excellent explanation. It helps a lot since I'm also currently working on a similar digital audio capture feature on a MSM based android device. :)

Comment: Will this work for voice calls, (all the virtual mic thing) cause i have many ideas involving this.

Comment: Well, not exactly. There may be different ALSA controls and additional steps involved. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432521/background-music-for-call/14433414#14433414 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204570/inject-uplink-audio-in-call-with-snapdragon-msm8960-soc/15205455#15205455

Comment: New link for ALSA UCM Settings: https://android.googlesource.com/device/lge/mako/+/jb-mr1-dev/snd_soc_msm_2x_Fusion3

Comment: @Michael, would you please refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42251267/modifying-in-call-voice-playback-in-android-custom-rom

It seems it could greatly benefit from your knowledge. If I could just make AudioSource.VOICE_DOWNLINK recording work on Nexus 5X, it would solve my problems. Or any better way you could think of. I'm working on a custom ROM so I can change anything that's needed.

Comment: @Michael Hello Mike, I am having a similar requirement. My requirement is for personal testing purpose. My app wont go to play store. I can change AOSP code, build and run to the device. You can also tell me which device to use, I would get the same device and rooted as well. I need to inject stored audio file into MIC. I would be making a VoIP call and inject the audio file as input to MIC. So that i can test the audio quality of received audio at the other end, over the network. My requirement is to test audio quality. Once VoIP call is setup, the only input to the MIC is my audio file.