# How to create new Android audio HAL that uses java byte[] as input?

Tags: android, audiorecord, hal, recognizer-intent

I want to write a PCM byte array in the RecognizerIntent so that it gets processed by it. Therefore I need an additional HAL that accepts byte arrays and writes them into a new AudioSource. As stated here [Redirecting audio / creating alternate sound paths in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024851/redirecting-audio-creating-alternate-sound-paths-in-android) this is hardware-dependent but could someone provide one example how to create this additional audio source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not possible without another hardware, as RecognizerIntent is basically a blackbox. But you could try to simulate a second microphone

Comment: is that possible? How would I simulate a mic in Android?