# Android record code audio

Tags: android, android-ndk, audio-recording, audioflinger

I'm writing a small call-recording application for my **rooted** phone.
I'm looking for a way to record audio directly from android system - or as low-level as possible, without using standard API's MediaRecorder or AudioRecord.
How can I do this? I can't find any good example on it, although I see it implemented in many apps (that require root).

Comment: You could try modifying the `AudioFlinger` to get the sort of functionality you want. But that is too broad a topic for a StackOverflow question. You'll just have to dig through [the Android source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/services/audioflinger/) to get an understanding of how things work and what you need to change/add.

Comment: There are also more platform-specific methods (see e.g. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024851/redirecting-audio-creating-alternate-sound-paths-in-android/21217919#21217919) where I do a brief summary of some experiments I did on a Qualcomm-based device). But again, just asking "how would I do that?" is too broad.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking for a less platform-specific solution. The AudioFlinger seems actually like a desired approach but I couldn't find a good entry point on how to use it in an Android app, and as I am not a c developer I'm struggling on how to use it...