# How to expose variable from HAL to shared libraries present in system/lib/hw (android)?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, hal

I made some changes in the platform specific existing HAL, and I want this changes to be get selected when I start my audio stream.

For this I need to differentiate it from other streams, so I added a variable in HAL and I wanted it to be exposed to my shared library that I will be pushing to system/lib/hw directory, so that when I start my stream I set this variable in my .so

So that in HAL I can differentiate it from other streams.

Any ideas to expose the variable in HAL to shared library in system/lib/hw ?

Suggestions/help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you add a new stream type (`AUDIO_STREAM_`), and possibly a new routing strategy (`STRATEGY_`). Then modify `getStrategy` in the `AudioPolicyManager` to return your new strategy when your new stream type is used, and modify `getDeviceForStrategy` to select the appropriate `DEVICE_OUT_` value for your new routing strategy.

Comment: Thanks again for quick reply.