# How the mixer thread created in Audio filnger and how the mapping is done between app and audio flinger mixer?

Tags: android, audio, audioflinger

I am trying to map this arch in the source code. As I checked in source code there are multiple threads created by audio flinger like direct output thread, mixer thread, offload thread, etc.

But I am not getting where should I change in configuration to create multiple mixer thread and how to map the data between app and mixer thread as shown in the below diagram.

just to mention the source of this arch is from- https://source.android.com/devices/automotive/audio

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Check these functions:

1. `AudioFlinger::PlaybackTrack::createTrack_l` for thread creation
2. `AudioPolicyManager::selectOutput` for the mapping