# Write custom audio stream to mic stream in android (with root privileges)

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to make an answering app for my personal use in android. Is there a convenient way using software tools (not Bluetooth or aux cables) in order to write custom audio stream in the mic stream during phone calls ?

PS: I have root privileges

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024851/redirecting-audio-creating-alternate-sound-paths-in-android/   In short: yes, it might be possible, but it might require you to create your own custom Android ROM.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possibile to send data/streams to the MIC expecially during the phone call.
When a voicecall is active the MIC is exclusively managed by a DIFFERENT chipset and it is disconnected from the internal Android mixer system. This behaviour makes the MIC temporarily unavailable for the whole System while in a voicecall.

Comment: are there any kernel modules to add in order to have have such feature ? I am using a custom ROM, so I guess I can recompile its kernel.

Comment: I don't think it could be "fixed" using a software. During the voicecall there is an "electrical switch" that redirects the MIC to the modem/GSM chip. This "switch_to" command (I think) it's sent by the GSM chips itself to take the ownership of the MIC while the voicecall is active. Even if it could be possibile to intercept/stop that "switch_to" command the result will be that the System mantains the ownership of the MIC but the GSM/modem chip cannot send your voice to the caller......so......

Comment: I rally believe that there is a way because I saw that some of the 3G USB dongles (which usually have similar modem chips as android devices) have the ability to communicate voice using a custom software on windows.  I think the trick is in a modified kernel that will give the ability to write raw bytes (data) in the device file of the mic.

Comment: I'm not sure USB 3G dongles makes REAL voicecall. Maybe a VOIp call. But event if these dongles makes voicecall, the mic+speakers are connected to a computer and there isn't any limit there where the mic should pass inside the INTERNAL Audio Card and THEN flows through the USB dongle.

Comment: @emandt Can you please provide a link with details about MIC, including the fact that during a voice call MIC is managed by a different chipset ? And has this been changed since your answer.