# Android Virtual Microphone

Tags: java, android, android-activity, virtual, voice

My question is more general and doesn't point to specific code segments. I would like to know is it possible to create a virtual microphone; for example when I connect my headset, my phone uses the microphone on the headset. Is there a way to create a virtual headset for which I specify a file to be read as it's input stream (or input from another device)? I've heard these sort of things are impossible due to hardware restrictions but I feel like there should be a way to create virtual devices which can pretend they are real external devices.

If the above is possible are there specific libraries or documentations which can help me since I did not find anything.

Comment: Your question does not follow the "what is wrong with my code" process that StackOverflow folks expect. You might find better results posting on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: My apologies for that. I'm looking for a starting point for my code. Not actually sure how to implement a virtual microphone.

Comment: Try posting on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Too much fun trying to figure out which community collection of folks would handle questions like these.  Wonder if we need to create a new forum on design and architecture questions.

Comment: I think if people could post ambigious questions on the most relevant forum, it would be the easiest instead of creating so many different forums.

Comment: It might be possible for you to do this if you're building your own Android ROM, but it would require a fairly deep understanding of the target platform. See e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255832/android-audio-loopback) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024851/redirecting-audio-creating-alternate-sound-paths-in-android/21217919#21217919) for some related info for Qualcomm platforms.

Comment: No I'm looking for a Stock ROM android compatible solution which works on most Android devices not just mine.

Comment: How could a bluetooth headset verify itself as a valid voice input then? (I'm hoping android does the final verification and not the kernel) I haven't really looked into the rom's and android kernels, since modifying them is not an option. But being able to add virtual devices will open a whole new window of applications. Some very interesting ones and some might abuse this capability.